# Iccube as a service in Windows server 2012?

Tags: windows, service, iccube

Trying to run iccube as a service on windows 2012R2, I had a look at this [page](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/running_iccube/service.php) but it looks like SRVANY is not 2012 compatable...

So, I used this command to create my service :

`C:\Windows\system32>sc create iccubeservice  binpath= "C:\Program Files\icCube\6.0.1\bin\icCube64.exe"`

the command answered with `[SC] CreateService réussite(s)`
Ok, I can see my service in windows services list, as well as in regedit... But can't start it...
I always get a `Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" when attempting to start, stop or pause a service`

**Edit :**

1) To clean everything, I executed `sc delete iccubeservice` and rebooted my server.  Nothing remaining in services nor Regedit.

2) I downloaded and installed [rktools.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

3) I ran in cmd as administrator `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools>instsrv "icCube Server Service" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\SRVANY.EXE"`
The new service appeared in services as wall as in the regedit.

4) Using Regedit, I added the `Parameters` key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\icCube Server Service`

5) in `Parameters`, I added the `Application` key with `C:\Program Files\icCube\6.0.1\bin\icCube64.exe`
[image]

Still Error 1053

Comment: Line one on that page states _"using SRVANY"_. You're not using SRVANY. You cannot register any executable as a service, SRVANY is a wrapper executable that _does_ respond to the service control manager in a way that it expects, which lets you do exactly that. Start by thoroughly reading that tutorial and precisely following all mentioned steps.

Comment: Ok, I followed the tuto using SRVANY.(I thought it was not 2003 compaable and that sc was the successor)  then added the Parameter key with regedit.  I'm still getting this Error 1053.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to list all steps you took.

Comment: Perhaps the process has started and then an error occured during the starting phase. So before starting the service, delete any existing icCube logs and try restarting the service. Tell us about that logs then.

Comment: Deleted all Log Files.  Tried to start the service. Same error.  Nothing in iccube's logfiles.

Comment: Any entries within the Windows event log ?

Comment: On top of the event log info, which account is running the service ?